# Why does solar cell performance use short-circuit current per unit area and open-circuit voltage without reference to the cell area?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

Here on this [slide on page 54](http://indico.ictp.it/event/a09136/session/4/contribution/3/material/0/0.pdf):

[image: solar cell table]

Only the short-circuit current ($J_{SC}$) is given with respect to area, whereas the voltage stands without relation to area. One could calculate it, because the area is given.

I just wondered, since I never heard about a open-circuit voltage density, but a lot about short-circuit current density.

Comment: Could you please spell out the acronyms?

Comment: VOC = Open-circuit voltage
JSC = Short-circuit current density
ISC = Short-circuit current

Comment: Again, I get downvoted for asking a question which should be understandable for everyone with basic knowledge of the field. 1 second on Google would also yield the answer. These are very common abbreviations. Not my fault. :/

Comment: @askingbecauseihavequestions I read "Vereenigde Oostindische Compagnie". Here area few more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOC

Comment: Solar cells and so are are part of electrical engineering. This is a basic physics site, so most of us  may know about the basics of semiconductor physics, but the language of the electrical enineering  is often unfamilar.

Comment: Okay, but in that case I would recommend to initially refrain from any judgement.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solar cell generates a current by collecting photons over its surface area. But solar cells come in many different sizes, so to allow them to be compared with each other the current is normalised by the area.

The open circuit voltage is not dependent on the area, but the other properties of the diode. It does have a dependence on illumination intensity. For this reason IV curves are quoted at standardised conditions.

Comment: But couldn't you say that a larger solar cell will also be able to store more energy, is a "stronger capacitor" in a way?

Comment: Got to be a bit careful with terminology because they don’t store energy, it’s being converted from sunlight and flowing out as current in a finite amount of time. It’s a stretch to call that storing energy. But I get what you mean. A larger cell has more photo generated electrons but the same number of photo generated electrons per unit area as smaller (or even larger) solar cell under the same illumination.

Comment: Yeah, the storage would only sustain as long as illumination would sustain and the individual electron-hole pairs (or should I say "excitons"?) recombine anyway really quickly. So, if you say they are the same with respect to unit area, why is there no VOC density (per unit area)? :/

Comment: Think of VOC as a constant of the material being used. In truth it is related to how the device is designed also but that’s not a bad approximation. It’s not a function of area. So has little meaning. You can of course plot it and convince yourself.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question and including the screenshot! But is ISC a function of the area? Shouldn't it be simply directly proportional to the area? And didn't you just say that the VOC increases with area? So it is also a (directly proportional) function of the area... sorry, I cannot wrap my head around this yet....

Comment: No VOC is not a function of area. It’s *weak* function of illumination intensity, but to first approximation you can think of it more like a material constant related to the band-gap of the semiconductor.

Comment: So it is only weakly correlated with the number of generated electron-hole pairs?

Comment: Yeah. VOC increases logarithmically with linear increase in intensity.

Comment: Mmh, I remember, it follows from the Shockley equation, but is that so little that we can neglect this?

Comment: Well normally solar cells are optimised and measured using the AM1.5 reference spectrum. So when you compare VOCs they should all be measured at the same illumination intensity so it does not matter. If they are not measured against a standard spectrum then there will be small variation. Whether that is negligible is dependent on your own criteria.

Comment: Mmh, I don't know if your answer satisfies my question. But right now I found a way of answering it myself: In the logarithmic equation for VOC we have a dependency on I_ph/I_0 (photo-generation current divided by saturation current). So it doesn't matter if we choose density or total current. Yes: A higher area would increase the electron-hole pairs, but it would also simply increase the recombination rate.

Comment: Great! Glad you have solved it, best way to learn.

Comment: Yes, I often learn by having conversations, so thank you as well!

Comment: The question got closed as well now... :O